# How do I run migration on multiple databases in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I have many databases that are prefixed. These all have the same database structure.

For Example:

- database_foo
- database_bar
- database_xyz

And these are constantly increasing.

I want to run migration on all database by prefix. How do I do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution I think.
You can create db connections in `config\database.php` as many as you want.
After that you can write migrations like this:

```
Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('some_table', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id'):
});
```

Comment: My databases are dynamically increasing. It's not static databases. If I have static databases i can run with this command; php artisan migrate --database=myconnection1

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have a main database where I store all information connection for all of the others database (Child database).

To run migration on each child database I put the code below.

Note that: **I have created 2 connection in Laravel. The default one and the second one, which I change dynamically on the run, depends on the client doing the request.** I think it's not efficient to create manually a connection in database for each client: I may have 100 client, so guess how will be the code there! And, in that way, you'll need to create specific models for each client too.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

use App\Models\Enseigne;

class CreateUserTable extends Migration
{
    private $Enseigne;
    private $dbClients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Here i'm loading my model and i'm geting all list of child connection from my main database
        $this->Enseigne = new Enseigne();
        $this->dbClients = $this->Enseigne->getAll();
    }

    private function switchDb($infosDb) 
    {
        config(['database.connections.client.host'      => $infosDb->dbhost]);
        config(['database.connections.client.port'      => $infosDb->dbport]);
        config(['database.connections.client.database'  => $infosDb->dbname]);
        config(['database.connections.client.username'  => $infosDb->dbuser]);
        config(['database.connections.client.password'  => $infosDb->dbpass]);
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Looping through mylist of connection
        foreach ($this->dbClients as $infosDb) {
            // Switching my connexion on my client connexion here
            $this->switchDb($infosDb);

            Schema::connection('client')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->timestamps();
            });

            // Note that purge, it's very important to clean the connection cache
            // Otherwise you'll migrate on the same DB even if you iterate it
            DB::purge('client');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection('client')->dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```